# Order_by error 1 10 11 12

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, helper

I am with a php code that is giving error in the Order_by this appearing the links in wrong orders was to appear 1 2 3 4 5.
and it is appearing 1 10 11 12

Can someone help me solve this?

```
$this->db->order_by('source_type', "DESC");
```

I think that although it is a strange problem it is very useful for many people who need to solve this problem .. I did not find anything on the internet that could help me with this

Comment: Make sure your `source_type` type is `INT`. It seems like `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your `source_type` field is declared as `VARCHAR`. If you try

```
SELECT '2' > '10'
```

You will get a result of 1 (true). So to make the values sort properly, you need to convert them to integers i.e.

```
ORDER BY CAST(source_type AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Without knowing your framework it's hard to know exactly how to specify that in the `order_by` method.